# Selection of Wi-Fi using AppleScript in Big Sur

Tags: applescript, wifi

I've tested the code below (from another question) and indeed it works fine, but I have minor problem with it. As my two SSIDs are called "kat" and "kat2", the expression "starts with" won't work for me.  I tried to replace it with "equals" or "ends with" but for these two options I get the result "missing value".

Any thoughts?

From URL: [Big Sur 11.1: AppleScript to Automatically Change Wi-Fi Networks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411111/big-sur-11-1-applescript-to-automatically-change-wi-fi-networks)

```
tell application "System Events" to click every menu bar item of menu bar 1 of application process "ControlCenter" whose title starts with "Wi‑Fi"
tell application "System Events" to click every UI element of scroll area of group 1 of window "Control Center" of application process "ControlCenter" whose title starts with "YOUR_SSID_HERE"
```

Comment: `whose title is equal to "YOUR_SSID_HERE"` works for me in **macOS Catalina**, but cannot test in **macOS Big Sur** at this time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I've found the problem. The issue is that the selection of the element, rather than returning "kat", it returns "kat, secure network, 2 bars" and that is why "ends with" or "equals" does not work. To fix that I can use "starts with" but adding a comma after YOUR_SSID_HERE.